# XSLT: remove a child when a parent has an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I wish to remove element `d` and comment `<!-- d -->` when the parent has attribute `c="string1"`

Input:

```
<a>
 <b c="string1">
   <!-- d -->
   <d>
     <e/>
   </d>
   <f/>
 </b>

 <b c="string2">
   <!-- d -->
   <d>
     <e/>
   </d>
   <f/>
 </b>
</a>
```

Desired output:

```
<a>
 <b c="string1">
   <f/>
 </b>

 <b c="string2">
   <!-- d -->
   <d>
     <e/>
   </d>
   <f/>
 </b>
</a>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

   <!-- Identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Those templates do not work -->
   <xsl:template match="d[???]" />
   <xsl:template match="comment()="d" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could look at it:

```
<xsl:template match="b[@c='string1']/d" />
<xsl:template match="b[@c='string1']/comment()[.=' d ']" />
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:template match="b[@c='string1']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::d or self::comment()[.=' d '])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Note that the value of the comment in the given example is actually `" d "` i.e. the character `"d"` surrounded by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. These two xsl:templates work.

```
<xsl:template match="d[ancestor::b[@c='string1']]" />
<xsl:template match="comment()[contains(.,'d') and ancestor::b[@c='string1']]" />
```

I would prefer not using `contains(.,'d')` but an equality expression on the text of the comment, but I don't know how to write that expression.

Comment: The equality expression you want would be `. = ' d ' `.  Do not overlook the spaces on both sides of the 'd'.

Comment: Additionally, it would be more conventional to use ordinary path expressions instead of predicate expressions testing nodes on the ancestor axis.  For example, `match="b[@c='string1']/d"`.